# Number of ways to finish a game

Tags: combinatorics

John and Shane are playing a game, where after each round you get 1 point if you win and lose 1 point if you lose the game.
The winner is the one who first reaches 4 points. In how many ways can any one of the players win?

I had this question in the exam yesterday and I was trying to solve it by taking either of the two possibilities game after game and add them all, but I thought it wouldn't work if in general if we have $n$ points for winning.

So can anyone help me show how to solve it?

Comment: I think there are infinite ways of winning. 
Assume John and Shane win alternately. After 2*n rounds their score would be each 0. Then John wins 4 rounds in a row. And he wins the game. For every natural number n exists 1 solution. (actually a lot more than one)

Comment: Do scores drop below zero? Is it always the case one wins and one loses?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I wanted to say at least $4$ times. Of yourse as you said it might be more actually $7$ at most. However the idea is that there is a certain number of differences and among them infinitely many oscillation is allowed.

Comment: As already said by others, there are infinitely countably ways of winning. However, if the game is fair, it takes 16 rounds in the mean before one of the players wins.

Comment: Could it be that the loser gets $0$ points instead of $-1$ points?

Comment: Maybe the answer is that there is only one way:  4 to -4.  Or maybe two ways, one for each player.  It sounds silly, but as user38034 shows, there is no useful answer if you count different orders of win/loss as different ways.

Answer (score 1):

If player a is awarded a point then player b loses a point and also the other way around. Therefore the final score is always going to be 4,-4 or -4,4. However there are infinite number of ways this can happen. The game can last 4 turns, 6 turns, 8 turns, any even number of turns. Therefore there are infinite ways it can happen but only two possible outcomes.